# List duplicates manipulation

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I am very new to python, and I am really lost right now. If anyone can help me, I will appreciate it a lot.
I have a list:

```
list1 = [((a, b), 2), ((a, b), 5), ((c, d), 1)), ((e, f), 2), ((e, f), 4)]
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
output = [((a, b), 7), ((c, d), 1), ((e, f), 6)]
```

I tried to put it in a dictionary

```
new_dict = {i: j for i, j in list1}
```

But it throws me an error

Maybe there are other ways?

Comment: "an error" is not particularly helpful. Please post the full error traceback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the explanation in the code comments

```py
list1 = [(('a', 'b'), 2), (('a', 'b'), 5), (('c', 'd'), 1), (('e', 'f'), 2), (('e', 'f'), 4)]

# let's create an empty dictionary
output = {}

# ('a', 'b') is a tuple and tuple is hashable so we can use it as dictionary key
# iterate over the list1

for i in list1:
    # for each item check if i[0] exist in output
    if i[0] in output:
        # if yes just add i[1]
        output[i[0]] += i[1]
    else:
        # create new key
        output[i[0]] = i[1]
        
# finally print the dictionary
final_output = list(output.items())
print(final_output)
```

```
[(('a', 'b'), 7), (('c', 'd'), 1), (('e', 'f'), 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{}.get` in this fashion:

```
list1 = [(('a', 'b'), 2), (('a', 'b'), 5), (('c', 'd'), 1), (('e', 'f'), 2), (('e', 'f'), 4)]

di={}
for t in list1:
    di[t[0]]=di.get(t[0],0)+t[1]

>>> di
{('a', 'b'): 7, ('c', 'd'): 1, ('e', 'f'): 6}
```

You can also use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter 

c=Counter({t[0]:t[1] for t in list1})

>>> c
Counter({('a', 'b'): 5, ('e', 'f'): 4, ('c', 'd'): 1})
```

Then to turn either of those into a list of tuples (as you have) you use `list` and `{}.items()`:

```
>>> list(c.items())
[(('a', 'b'), 5), (('c', 'd'), 1), (('e', 'f'), 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [(('a', 'b'), 2), (('a', 'b'), 5), (('c', 'd'), 1), (('e', 'f'), 2), (('e', 'f'), 4)]
sorted_dict = {}
for ele in list1:
    if ele[0] in sorted_dict:
        sorted_dict[ele[0]] += ele[1]
    else:
        sorted_dict[ele[0]] = ele[1]
print(sorted_dict)
```